# How to convert DEC 64bit double precision floating point to IEEE-754 (DEC is not decimal)

Tags: c, floating-point, binary

To clarify here DEC in this case is Digital Equipment Corporation NOT decimal. What I have is a binary representation of DEC with seeeeeeeefffff....(total f's is 54) s = sign bit, e = exponent, f = fraction and I need to convert that into an IEEE-754 format preferably with the same precision. To put into context this represents a utc time tag for gps. I have become increasingly confused on the terminolgy as I have found multiple names that might represent DEC and might not. For example VAX-ll, DEC64, PDP-11 and I've tried all of them without much success.

Here is the raw data (in hex) that represents a UTC time tag in DEC dpfp for reference and what its approx. supposed to be: (keep in mind this data is LITTLE ENDIAN and IEEE-754 should be big endian)

```
0x99, 0x48, 0xD9, 0xE4, 0x12, 0xF3, 0xF9, 0xF0 = 1608587778
```

I believe [PDP-11](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nssdc/formats/PDP-11.htm) or [VAX](http://yaadc.blogspot.com/2013/01/vax-ffloat-and-dfloat-to-ieee-tfloat.html) to be more likely

Comment: Note that the [VAX-11 has two *different* types](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nssdc/formats/VAXFloatingPoint.htm) of 64-bit floating-point representations.

Comment: Endianness is a separate issue. Different systems may store IEEE-754 double in different byte orders. The important part is to read the DEC double as a 64-bit unsigned value, and then use it to produce an IEEE-754 double as a 64-bit unsigned value (or directly as a C `double` if the implementation uses IEEE-754 natively).

Comment: @IanAbbott I'm not sure I'm understanding you, are you saying that I don't need to do any juggling with the bits to convert to IEEE-754? Lets pretend everything is big endian for simplicity. (my code does support IEEE-754 natively fyi)

Comment: @robell You _do_ need to juggle the bits.

Comment: @IanAbbott ok, then that's the part I'm having trouble with, do you know or have any source material I could reference?

Comment: IEEE-754 formats documentation should be easy to find, e.g. from Wikipedia, but I have no idea about the DEC formats, other than that there seems to be more than one of them.

Comment: With "What I have is a binary representation of DEC with seeeeeeeefffff....(total f's is 54)", note that is 63 characters.

Comment: The PDP-11 format you linked is a 32-bit format.

Comment: The most-significant bit of the first byte cannot be the sign bit, else the result would be negative.  Same for the last byte (accounting for a possible full reversal of all 8 bytes).  The same also for the fourth byte (accounting for a possible full reversal of each 32-bit word).  Only the second and fifth bytes are candidates for having the sign bit as their MSB.

Comment: Continuing my forensic analysis, I took the supposed decimal equivalent and looked at its hexadecimal representation, and also the hex representations of the results of shifting the original value left by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7 bits.  The idea was that even if the starting pattern was out of register, and some precision was lost, I ought to be able in one of those patterns to find a match at least to a pair of bytes from the byte sequence presented.  I did not find any such pair.  In fact, only one of the 32 full bytes I generated that way appears in the given sequence.

Comment: I also looked more closely at trying to identify the sign / exponent.  The specified decimal value requires 31 bits, so in a binary floating-point format, the exponent part will be a biased version of 31.  Neither a 128-bit bias nor a 1024-bit bias yields a sign/exponent byte that appears among the specified bytes.

Comment: With all that, I have pretty much convinced myself that the byte sequence presented does not correspond to the given decimal representation, even approximately, in any plausible 64-bit binary floating point format.  Perhaps something exotic has happened, such as a *bit*wise reversal, but I'm done looking.  You should look into the documentation and context of the system that emitted the data to determine its format.  Even its source code, if that is available.

Comment: @JohnBollinger THANK YOU for looking into this so deeply you have confirmed some worries that I had, I mean you cant just say "its not my code thats wrong , its the data" without some serious proof.

Comment: Isn't it a case of exotic middle endianness? Like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Middle-endian, PDP 11 is cited as an example...

Answer (score 0):

You may find the package *libvaxdata* [1](https://pubs.usgs.gov/of/2005/1424/) does what you need.  I haven't used it but it claims to offer routines to convert between IEEE and VAX floating point types. (It can be used for PDP-11 data as well). There is a document describing the routines.